# JS form validation for dynamically built form in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, datatables

EDIT: I am using Foundation 6 with the [Abide Form Validation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/abide.html).

I'm trying to do automatic form validation for a website. What I've done is create a table (using the [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) library) with a series of inputs in the first row. Then the user uses an 'add new row' button to add more rows (with identical input fields, but unique names/ids) as needed.

Everything is working fine so far, except now when I am attempting to validate the inputs, only the first row is being checked. I'm new to JS and jQuery, so I'm picking up a lot of this stuff as I go, but I think what I'm trying to do is refresh the table's DOM element so that the newly added inputs are included in validation. I just can't seem to figure out how to get the DOM to refresh.

The actual table and scripts are complicated, so in the interest of simplicity the code below is a simplified version of what I'm working with:

**HTML:**

```
<form data-abide novalidate action="processRequest.php" method="post" name="processRequest">
  <button class="button">Submit Request</button>
  <table id="Request" class="display">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type*</th>
        <th>Product*</th>
        <th>Command*</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="RequestType0" id="RequestType0" required>
            <option></option>
            <option>New</option>
            <option>Resize</option>
            <option>Restyle</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="RequestProduct0" id="RequestProduct0" required>
            <option></option>
            <option>Product1</option>                   
            <option>Product4</option>
            <option>Product3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="RequestCommand0" id="RequestCommand0" placeholder="Command" required/>
        </td>                                   
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Add new row -->
  <button class="button" id="add_row" type="button"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

**jQuery Datatables Construction Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#Request').DataTable( {
    "ordering": false, // Globally disables reordering of the table on all columns
    "bLengthChange": false, // Disable user ability to change # of results shown
    "searching": false, // Disable user search filtering field
    "info": false, // Disable info box 
    "processing": false, // Disable showing the 'processing' indicator on refresh
    "paging": false, // Disables paging
  } );
} );
```

**Add New Row Script:**

```
$('#add_row').on("click", function newRow() {
    var table = $('#Request').DataTable().rows();
    var len = table.rows().count();

    var cell0 = table.cell(len-1,0).node();
    var cell1 = table.cell(len-1,1).node();
    var cell2 = table.cell(len-1,2).node();

    table.row.add( [cell0.innerHTML, cell1.innerHTML, cell2.innerHTML] ).draw(true);

    table.cell(len,0).node().childNodes[1].setAttribute('name', 'RequestType' + len);
    table.cell(len,0).node().childNodes[1].setAttribute('id', 'RequestType' + len);
    table.cell(len,1).node().childNodes[1].setAttribute('name', 'RequestProduct' + len);
    table.cell(len,1).node().childNodes[1].setAttribute('id', 'RequestProduct' + len);
    table.cell(len,2).node().childNodes[1].setAttribute('name', 'RequestCommand' + len);
    table.cell(len,2).node().childNodes[1].setAttribute('id', 'RequestCommand' + len);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `data-abide` attribute, I assume you are using [Abide Validation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/abide.html).

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#adding-content-to-plugins

> In previous versions of Foundation, there was a method for plugins
>   called `reflow`, though its inclusion on plugins wasn't universal. For
>   Foundation 6 we've added a global `reInit` method that will remove and
>   reapply event listeners, update the plugin's instance data for
>   relevant information, like a new tab or content pane being added, and
>   reset any cached data the plugin may rely on.

You need to run this code each time a row is added:

```
Foundation.reInit('abide');
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for the pointer. This isn't working for me unfortunately (I'm using Foundation 6.0.1, and this is for 5.5.3) but I'll do some digging. If I find an answer I'll post it here

Comment: @enpaul: With Foundation 6, the equivalent [seems to be](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#adding-content-to-plugins): `Foundation.reInit('abide');`. I will update my answer if that works for you. Your question would have been easier to answer if you included that you were using Foundation 6, since the answer is specific to that framework.

Comment: thanks so much! that line worked perfectly. Adding `Foundation.reInit('abide'); to the end of `newRow();` solved the problem. I'll be sure to include details like that in future posts; I'm somewhat new here and still getting used to things, so thanks for your patience and help!
Is that in the main F6 docs? If not, could you post a link to where you found that information?

Comment: @enpaul: You're welcome. The link is in my above comment. I will edit my answer to include it too.